# Share button for a new playlist

Tags: spotify

How can I show a share popup for a playlist I created by like this?

```
var playlist = new models.Playlist("My cool playlist");
```

As the uri is not available for the new playlist due to security policies, how can I allow the user to share the playlist though the standard share popup? The showSharePopup does not accept an instance of playlist but without any URI I don't know how to do? 
 The reason for asking is that I'm working on an app for distribution on App FInder and they want me to make it possible to share new playlists from the app in the next update.

Answer (score 1):

> ...and they want me to make it possible to share new playlists from the app in the next update.

If you have someone in Spotify asking you to do something that seems impossible, it's probably a good idea to ask them how they want you to do it!